# L.marker moving(update) from the map using setInterval in html with database?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, react-leaflet

Hello i'm just wondering if this is possible to make a moving L.markers from the map using setInterval? my database is always updated. Can someone help me with my problem? sorry i'm only a freshmen.

```
 var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
      function myTimer() {
       markers.clearLayers();
        for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
            var option;
          
        
                    marker = new L.marker([planes[i][2],planes[i][3]], {icon: option}).addTo(markers);
                    marker.bindPopup('Employee: ' + planes[i][0] + '<br>Department: ' + planes[i][1] + '<br>Date Log: ' + planes[i][4]) 
                    .openPopup()
                    .addTo(markers);             
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: My L.marker wont move from the map :( i want to move the marker from the map using time set interval because i am using updated dbase.

Comment: Based on my research i cant find any moving markers in leaflet html using dbase.